# How can I use filereader to parse csv file and convert it into an array?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, filereader

I have this in my html page:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
```

and this in my javascript page:

```
window.onload = function () {
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    // code that handles reading the text file
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var textType = /text.*/;
    // checks if the file is a text file
       if (file.type.match(textType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
            }

            reader.readAsText(file);
        } else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!";
        }
    });
}
```

I want to be able to convert the Filereader into an array so I can do something like:

```
document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = today[0];
```

Is this possible? I also don't think this is the way to read a csv file using filereader.

UPDATE: I have figured out how to get the csv file and turn it into an array by the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) { processData(data); }
    });
    function processData(csv) {
        var temp = new Array();
        temp = csv.split(",");
        document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = temp[0];
    }
});
```

Now I am wondering if there is a way to use FileReader() so I can select the file from the html page instead of using `url: "data.csv"` so I can select multiple files.

Comment: you'd have to parse the csv first. as is, you're just slurping up the entire file and stuffing it into a text node. that means it's just one huge text string as far as JS/DOM is concernted.

Comment: First, I'd strongly recommend you to use a CSV parsing library, rather than doing the `split`s by yourself. It will save you headaches (think different possible line breaking characters, or column separators, escaped characters etc. [Papaparse](http://papaparse.com/) is powerful, fully-featured, well designed.

Then, yes, you may use fileReader. See papaParse example [here](http://papaparse.com/#local-files) (apply that logic even if you don't use papaparse).

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this a few ways.  You might think to ajax the file to a PHP script, then do something like `$csvData[] = fgetcsv($file)`.  Then you can `echo json_encode($csvData);`.  It may be an extra http/server request but processing files is much easier.

There are some Javascript libraries that you wouldn't need to run server-side scripts for - [JQuery CSV](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/) and [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com/)